# Restore Solr 4.1 index to pioint in time from transaction logs?

Tags: solr

I accidently replaced my useful documents, by deleting all of them and inserting others. I noticed I have the transaction logs. Is there a way to restore the index to a point in time from the same?

BTW, its useful but not critical data, but somebody may need to recover critical stuff :-)

Comment: Is there a `deletionPolicy` configured in your `solrconfig.xml`? If yes, would you update it in your question? It could look [like this in the reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexConfig+in+SolrConfig#IndexConfiginSolrConfig-OtherIndexingSettings).

Comment: It has never been configured( same as stock: the stuff is commented)

Comment: yes it is possible see my comment in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160945/it-is-possible-to-restore-document-in-solr-usinf-tlog-file/58972530#58972530
regards Madde

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to recover lost data (or if that's even possible). But to prevent this from happening again, you can use Solr's Replication to create regular backups. Configuration would look something like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
  <lst name="master">
    <str name="enable">true</str>
    <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
    <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>

    <str name="backupAfter">optimize</str>
    <str name="maxNumberOfBackups">3</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Full configurations options are described in [Solr Replication Configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#Master)

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, no you cannot use tlogs for this.

After having read "[Hard commits, soft commits and transaction logs](http://searchhub.org/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/)" especially the first smaller section about transactionlogs

> Transaction log (tlog): A file where the raw documents are written for *recovery purposes*. In SolrCloud, each node has its own tlog. On update, the entire document gets written to the tlog. For Atomic Updates, it’s still the entire document, including data read from the old version of the document. In other words, the document written to the tlog is not the “delta” for atomic updates. Tlogs are critical for consistency, *they are used to bring an index up to date if the JVM is stopped before segments get closed*.

So the tlogs are there for data consistency not for backups.

Answer (score 0):

Reference answer:
[It is possible to restore document in solr usinf tlog file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160945/it-is-possible-to-restore-document-in-solr-usinf-tlog-file/58972530#58972530)

I also got the same problem, I found a solution (workaround): open your tlog file and remove at the end of the file "ƒD`-SOLR_TLOG_END " then start your solr the content of the tlog file is indexed/commitet to the index. In my testcase I only hat one tlog file in the folder.

To find out the chars which you should delete just add in the admin webinterface under "Documents" a example document with "commit within" 100000 value afer that stop immediately the solr. It is important that you stop the solr before solr does the commit (commit within time should be high). Then copy the new tlog file on your desktop or an other folder. Start the solr again and compare the two files, then you will see after the tlog is added to the index solr appends the "ƒD`-SOLR_TLOG_END " string.

short information: tlog is used to add documents to the index if the solr goes down without the commit. if the solr gets up again the tlog is used to add the not committed documents to the index.