# It is possible to restore document in solr usinf tlog file

Tags: solr

Every time when i add/update document in solr , tlog file maintains the request query for each commit.

**example:** 
**when i commit using update command:**

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/sample_list/update' --data-binary '{"add":{"doc":{ "id":"7","name":"test dfasdata jan565765"}},"commit":{}}'
```

**tlog file content look likes:**

^B
^B)SOLR_TLOGA'strings<83>"id$name)*version*^@^@^@)<83>A^G^VYîÖ·^@^@^@^P^C^H?<80>^@^@á!7â7test dfasdata jan565765ã^G^VYîÖ·^@^@^@^@^@^@8<83>D`-SOLR_TLOG_END^@^@^@^Q

It is possible to execute the request query in tlog file for recovery purpose which is not in readable format?

Comment: Are you asking about manually executing the statements from the transaction log? If Solr goes down, it should replay the required part of the transaction load automagically.

Comment: yes, when solr is down based on the transaction log the same query should be executed once.It is possible to execute the transaction log query??

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I found a solution / workaround:

1. open your tlog file
2. remove at the end of the file "ƒD`-SOLR_TLOG_END   "
3. start solr
4. the content of the tlog file is indexed/committed to the index.

In my testcase I only had one tlog file in the folder.

To find out the chars which you should delete, just add in the admin webinterface under "Documents" a example document with "commit within" 100000 value afer that stop immediately solr.
It is important that you stop solr before solr does the commit (commit within time should be high).
Then copy the new tlog file on your desktop or an other folder.
Start solr again and compare the two files, then you will see after the tlog is added to the index solr appends the "ƒD`-SOLR_TLOG_END   " string.

**In short:**
tlog is used to add documents to the index if solr goes down before committing; if solr gets up again the tlog is used to add the documents not yet commited to the index.